# Proof of Borel-Weil-Bott Theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is there any purely algebraic proof of Borel-Weil-Bott theorem. I mean only techniques from Algebraic group. In each and every proof I have seen so far they use Lie group techniques and then translate to Algebraic group version. I need a proper reference which is easily readable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a proof by Lunts-Rosenberg on quantum analogue of Borel-weil-Bott theorem using purely algebraic or algebraic geometry(categorical geometry)way. Check out the paper: localization for quantum group

Answer (score 13):

The simplest proof of Borel-Weil-Bott that I know is due to Demazure: he has two papers in Inventiones (one in 1968 the other in 1976) on the theorem, and the second is two pages long -- it gives a simplification of his previous proof, and he uses only algebro-geometric techniques. Both papers are readable.

Answer (score 7):

Near the bottom of [Jacob Lurie's homepage](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/), you can find an exposition of the Borel-Weil-Bott theorem from an algebro-geometric standpoint.  It is "easily readable" if you're familiar with the things like line bundles on projective varieties, semisimple algebraic groups, etc..

Answer (score 3):

See J.C. Jantzen "Representations of Algebraic Groups" II.5 especially II.5.5.

There you will find an algebraic proof of the result in char. 0 (probably more-or-less
Demazure's proof, mentioned in another answer). And you'll find a proof of some of
what remains true in positive char (due to Henning Anderson).

Comment: Demazure's approach is certainly the most useful from the viewpoint
of algebraic geometry in characteristic 0, but the related questions
in characteristic `$p>0$` remain to a large extent open and are
natural follow-ups.   As George indicates, Jantzen's book provides
access to such questions in a unified framework.   Andersen
got started on his own work partly by exploring how Demazure's 
set-up might be adapted to characteristic `$p$`.    But a full
analogue of Bott's theorem probably requires some creative use
of Kazhdan-Lusztig theory for the affine Weyl group.  
