# Borel–Weil theorem - reference request

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups

I am asking about good references (both books and papers) for the well-known Borel–Weil theorem. Thank you very much!

Comment: This question largely duplicates the earlier one on MO 13657. (Also, note the analytic approach in the 2002 AMS graduate text by J.L. Taylor on several complex variables etc.) 

Comment: thank you very much for the AMS graduate text and the analytic approach. I have not noticed it before!I will check it


Comment: Here is a link to the question mentioned in Jim Humphreys' comment above: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13657/proof-of-borel-weil-bott-theorem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

J.P. Serre: "Représentations linéaires et espaces homogènes kählériens des groupes de Lie compacts (d'après Armand Borel et André Weil)", Séminaire Bourbaki (Paris: Soc. Math. France) 2 (100), 1995, 447–454.

J. Tits: "Sur certaines classes d'espaces homogènes de groupes de Lie, Acad. Roy. Belg. Cl. Sci. Mém. Coll. 29 (1995).

M. Sepanski: Compact Lie groups., Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 235, New York, Springer, 1995. (Theorem 7.58).

Comment: thank you very much, Sepanski's book has a  paragraph devoted to Borel-Weil theorem!

Answer (score 4):

Chapter II.5 in Jantzen's *Representations of Algebraic Groups* offers an algebraic treatment of this theorem.

Comment: If you're looking for Borel-Weil-Bott theory in positive characteristic, this book is definitely the best exposition I know of.