# Your favourite alternative proof of Borel–Weil–Bott

Tags: rt.representation-theory, geometric-representation-theory, flag-varieties

There is a really nice proof of Borel–Weil–Bott, essentially using parabolic induction (see [Proof of Borel-Weil-Bott Theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13657/proof-of-borel-weil-bott-theorem), [Lurie - A proof of the Borel–Weil–Bott theorem](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Elurie/papers/bwb.pdf) or [Demazure - A very simple proof of Bott's theorem](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN356556735_0033?tify=%7B%22pages%22:%5B277%5D,%22panX%22:0.554,%22panY%22:0.432,%22view%22:%22info%22,%22zoom%22:0.567%7D)). Also, presumably there is a proof if you take the BGG resolution as given, and compare to the Weyl character formula.

However, because of the philosophy that it's worth knowing many proofs of a really fundamental result, I want to ask the

**Question:** What is your favourite (fundamentally different to the above) proof of Borel–Weil–Bott?